# Can't initialize an enum with a value from its underlying type

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

```
enum class Color { red, blue, green };
Color x = Color{5};
```

The second statement gives me error **(main.cpp:20:23: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘Color’ in initialization)**. I was going through the c++ book it says it's OK to initialize the way in the second statement. I'm confused whether can we use int in initializing the enum type (Color here).

Comment: You have to set the C++ version to C++17: [C++14](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3YUL0uwe7n7UMxiA) [C++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KsaQsRI6SAQgQiQG) It's described in [cpprerference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization of scope enumerations with an integer without cast is a C++17 feature, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations). You have to enable C++17 in your compile step.